# laravel socialite youtube api get videos

Tags: laravel, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, laravel-socialite

I am trying to get a users uploaded videos on youtube.

My Project is build on Laravel.
I am using socialite to auth the user. I get the user to login via google, and also authenticate via youtube.

What i see in socialite is, that its only getting the user informations.
in socialiteproviders/youtube/Provider.php i can see that its making a get request to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true
```

passing the token which responded from the auth.

I would like to get a List of the videos from the logged in user. How is the best way to do it in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

The Youtube Socialite Provider only fetches a list of channels for the current user. This is what the response looks like:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    channel Resource
  ]
}
```

from [Youtube documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#response).

To fetch a list of uploaded videos, you will have to call the API yourself.

To do this, you want to fetch the playlist that the user's uploads reside on from [contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads):

> **string** 
>   The ID of the playlist that contains the channel's uploaded
>   videos. Use the videos.insert method to upload new videos and the
>   videos.delete method to delete previously uploaded videos.

Once you've done that, you can get a list of [playlist items](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list).